# Expectation of Gamma Distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim \Gamma(n , 1)$, I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}(|X - n|)$.
Is there any good approach?

Comment: Yes: compute the expectation of $X-n$ on the event $[X-n\geqslant0]$.

Comment: Any progress with the hint above?

Comment: @DidierPiau Currently no, I found it a bit hard to get the result.

Comment: Do you know the density of the distribution of $X$?

Comment: Got something from the comments above?